# To detect current geo location in mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, geolocation, gps

I've used below code to detect the current location in angular app. this is working fine with all the desktop browser but it not working in mobile device please find below code for more understanding.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onPositionUpdate,locNotFound,{frequency:5000,maximumAge: 0, timeout: 100, enableHighAccuracy:true});
} else {
    // nothing 
}

function locNotFound () {
    console.log('location not found');
}
function onPositionUpdate(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + lng + "&sensor=true";
    $http.get(url)
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
}
```

As you can see that locNotFound() function is called in mobile device. which it should not do because GPS on in mobile device.

Comment: what kind of device?

Comment: I tried in Android (chrome, mozilla) and iOS (safari) did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just can give you a partial answer for Android.

Please open the Chrome Browser at Android, click at the icon top right (the tree dots), click at Settings, click at Site Settings and please check the settings for Location. As far as I know this is disabled per default.

So I think your problem is related to security restrictions

Regards

Michael

Comment: Thanks Michael for your input's. I tried this but it still not work for me.